# How to read "k/2th element" in speaking?

Tags: pronunciation

I know how to read ordinal numbers and fractions, but for this "k/2th element", I do not know how to read.
What I mean is the following:

- k half element
- k second element
- k slash second element (read this one by one)

Maybe, there is something else. I want to know how to read this naturally, not weirdly like a machine.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by the above. Can you give some examples with actual numbers?

Comment: @PRL75 I wrote comments in detail on a programming problem to avoid forgetting it later. Let me add a little background. There is an array and we suppose that A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}. The position where we describe the value of A starts at 0, called index 0 (first element).  So, let we assume that there are k elements in an array and we cut this in half and then drop the first half. In other words, the first element to the  k/2th element are discarded. Sometimes, I need to explain that the code how to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would normally say: *"The first n elements are discarded"*.

You could also say: *"All elements up to the n th are discarded"*.

The first is probably better because you would really need to say: *""All elements up to **and including** the n th are discarded"."* to avoid ambiguity. (Although, that might be clear from the context.)

Answer (score 1):

As a native English speaker with a university degree in computer science, I would read "k/2th element" as "k on two-th element". That is, "k on two" is the number that is being made ordinal, so you use the suffix "th" to make it ordinal.

Comment: I would say k over 2-th but otherwise I think this is the way to go.

Comment: So, you would say: *"the first k on twoth elements are discarded" . I' have a computer science degree, and I would have no idea what that meant. I'm pretty sure you are wrong, though.  Can you give an using  actual  numbers?

Comment: @PRL75 Nope, I'd probably say "the first k on five-th elements are discarded", though that's a bit of a tongue twister because of how that would be pronounced.

Comment: @nick012000 I'm completely confused, now.  Your example sounds weird. The natural way of saying this is: *"The first k over 5 elements are discarded"*. There's absolutely no need to use weird non standard tongue twisters. Maybe it's a regional thing, but I have **never** heard **anyone** say *"x **on** y"* to denote division. *"x **over** y"*, or occasionally *"x **by** y"*, but never *"x on y"*.

Comment: @PRL75 "Maybe it's a regional thing, but I have never heard anyone say "x on y" to denote division." It's probably a British English or Australian English thing, then.

Comment: Does the "two-th" really exist? Is it informal in speaking? I always think it's "second" and not "two-th".

Comment: @nick012000 no, in BrE we say over not on. I cannot speak for other dialects.

Comment: @asdfjoe usually yes but here two-th is used because k over second would be meaningless.

Comment: @mdewey okay, I see how the voice that speaks in my head interprets it. Thanks